# Using XDocument how do I add a serialized/xml representation of a class as an element of XDocument?

Tags: xml, linq, c#-4.0, linq-to-xml

I am trying to convert a class/object to an XElement and insert it into an XDocument that I am loading from a disk based template.

```
        Recipient rec = new Recipient();
        rec.Body_Type = "HTML";
        rec.Email = "Testaddress@gmail.com";
        XDocument myDoc =XDocument.Load("../../MasterTemplate.xml");

       //serialize Recipient to element and add it

        myDoc.Root.Add(element);
        this.richTextBox1.Text =  myDoc.ToString();
```

I assume that I will need to serialize the object in some way but am not sure exactly how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible approaches (efficiency not taken into account) :

1. You can serialize the object to XML string using serializer, then convert the string to `XElement` using `XElement.Parse()`.
2. or manually create `XElement` using linq-to-xml.

After one of those, you have `XElement`(s) ready to be inserted to your existing `XDocument`. Assuming that `Recipient` class is simple class containing only two properties of type string, then the 2nd approach is more convenient in my opinion, for example :

```
XElement element = 
            new XElement("Recipient",
                             new XElement("Body_Type", rec.Body_Type),
                             new XElement("Email", rec.Email));
myDoc.Root.Add(element);
```

For reference : [MSDN: Creating XML Trees in C# (LINQ to XML)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387089.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what 'element' is makes the question more difficult.  Let's say it is a complex type with other properties that can be exposed as strings of 'Name' and 'Value' for example.

You are missing instantiating a new instantiation 'XElement' and I am not certain if you wish to add to the root directly.  EG:

```
myDoc.Root.Add(element)
```

becomes:

```
myDoc.Add(new XElement("My Element Name", new XAttribute("My Attribute", element.Name), element.Value));
```

I am thus adding an element to the xdoc by properly calling the addition of an 'XElement'.  The Element added has a name of 'My Element Name'.  I decide to include a XAttribute that is named 'My Attribute' but a 'Name' from a type of element.  Then the text included is the 'Value' from element.

IMHO I do not like creating XML from XDocument.  It is far better to create your own complex types and then make a custom serializer with 'System.Xml.Serialization' than all of the complex rules of adding xml to xdocs.  But it depends on preference and project scope as well.